# How to install git for CentOS?

Tags: centos, yum

I tried several suggestions from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/337399/cant-install-git-on-a-centos-6-0-x64) but none of them worked.

```
[root@308321 sugar-dev]# yum install git
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * epel: www.gtlib.gatech.edu
 * extras: mirrors.usinternet.com
 * updates: mirrors.serveraxis.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.8.2.1-1.el5 for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Error) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.0()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-expat1.x86_64 0:1.95.8-8.el6 will be installed
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package openssl098e.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-17.el6.centos.2 will be installed
---> Package perl-Error.noarch 1:0.17015-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-Git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-Git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package perl-TermReadKey.x86_64 0:2.30-13.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: perl-Git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@308321 sugar-dev]# yum -y install git --disablerepo=updates
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * epel: www.gtlib.gatech.edu
 * extras: mirrors.usinternet.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.8.2.1-1.el5 for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Error) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.0()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-expat1.x86_64 0:1.95.8-8.el6 will be installed
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package openssl098e.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-17.el6.centos.2 will be installed
---> Package perl-Error.noarch 1:0.17015-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-Git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-Git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package perl-TermReadKey.x86_64 0:2.30-13.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: perl-Git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@308321 sugar-dev]# yum install git --disableexcludes=main --skip-broken
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * epel: www.gtlib.gatech.edu
 * extras: mirrors.usinternet.com
 * updates: mirrors.serveraxis.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.8.2.1-1.el5 for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Error) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.0()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-expat1.x86_64 0:1.95.8-8.el6 will be installed
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package openssl098e.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-17.el6.centos.2 will be installed
---> Package perl-Error.noarch 1:0.17015-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-Git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-Git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package perl-TermReadKey.x86_64 0:2.30-13.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    compat-expat1-1.95.8-8.el6.x86_64 from base
    git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64 from epel
    openssl098e-0.9.8e-17.el6.centos.2.x86_64 from base
    1:perl-Error-0.17015-4.el6.noarch from base
    perl-Git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64 from epel
    perl-TermReadKey-2.30-13.el6.x86_64 from base
[root@308321 sugar-dev]# git
-bash: git: command not found
[root@308321 sugar-dev]#


[root@308321 sugar-dev]# uname -a
Linux 308321.oliveyou.net 2.6.32-220.2.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 23 02:21:33 CST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Which version of CentOS is this? And did you install any third party software at all?

Comment: List the repositories you are using too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your problem is not too few versions of `git` available, but too many; `git` is in the base/updates repo set, but a newer version is also in epel, and they are treading on each other's feet.  You also appear to have an old version of the epel repo wired in (it's picking up `.el5` packages), and that **definitely** won't be helping.

Try

```
yum install git --disablerepo=epel
```

which should get you get 1.7.1.  If that works, you might also want to fix your epel repo (it's in `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`) and to look into repository prioritisation, which helps prevents newer versions of tools (usually from add-on repos) from treading on older versions (from core repos) unless you specifically ask for them to do so.

Comment: Disabling all but base repos did not work, in my case.  In any case, the user should never see any of this.  The conflict-errors shown are only useful as OS-developer bug-fixing feedback.

Comment: Not at all, they're very useful to the user in terms of understanding that conflicts exist.  The latest yum replacement, `dnf`, doesn't display this information (at least not for me, on Fedora 22, and no amount of adding `--best` will make it do so), and I *really* miss it.  That said, I'm sorry that you're having a problem; it may be worth posting a question, referencing this one.

Answer (score 5):

You should also check CentOS wiki article on repositories

http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories

where You will find some info on content duplication.

You could also experiment with Yum plugins: **Priorities** or **ProtectBase**.

Those should help in managing 3rd party package sources.

Comment: Thanks. I had epel5 installed, so replaced with epel6 and changed `enabled=0` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`.